# How does Tomcat locate the webapps directory?

Tags: tomcat

How does Tomcat locate webapps directory? Where is this location set? Is it a relative directory?

Comment: The location of the `webapps` directory is relative to the Tomcat installation directory, which is known by Tomcat. Why are you asking?

Comment: My motivation is complex :) Just answer if you know. Your answer means `webapps` is relative to `CATALINA_HOME` or what?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It can be changed in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` in the `<Host />` element.

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
```

---

See the Tomcat documentation, specifically the section in regards to the Host container:

[Tomcat 6 Configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html)

[Tomcat 7 Configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html)

[Tomcat 8 Configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html)

[Tomcat 9 Configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html)

[Tomcat 10 Configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/host.html)

The default is `webapps` relative to the `$CATALINA_BASE`. An absolute pathname can be used.

[image]

Comment: Works on Tomcat 8 too.
[Tomcat 8 Configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html)

Answer (score 15):

Find server.xml at `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`

Find `appBase` attribute in `<Host>` element

by default it will be something like :
`<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps ...>`

Change appBase to your required path. There are different way people put it, but I use

```
/c:/myfolder/newwebapps
```

Remember, no slash at the end, but at start. Also note it's direction as well.

Answer (score 4):

Change `appBase` in `server.xml`

If you want to keep both previous webapps and a new one, you can use another Host instance with another port defined in tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Tomcat through XAMPP which might have been the cause of this problem. When I changed `appBase="C:/Java Project/"`, for example, I kept getting `"This localhost page can't be found"` in the browser.

I had to add a folder called ROOT inside the Java Project folder and then it worked. Any files you're working on have to be inside this ROOT folder but you need to leave `appBase="C:/Java Project/"` as changing it to `appBase="C:/Java Project/ROOT"` will cause `"This localhost page can't be found"` to be displayed again.

Maybe needing the ROOT folder is obvious to more experienced Java developers but it wasn't for me so hopefully this helps anyone else encountering the same problem.