# how to access web application by only mygodaddydomainname.com instead of mygodaddydomainname.com/webappname/pagename.jsp

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications, dns, godaddy-api

I have a webapp in eclipse..it is already running through localhost/webappname/pagename.jsp ... 
now i buyed a static ip and did port forwarding... 
now i am able to access it through internet by mystaticip/webappname/pagename.jsp ... 
now i bought a domain name from godaddy for my static ip... 
i configured domain name for my static ip in DNS manager... 
now i am able to access it through internet by mygodaddydomainname.com/webappname/pagename.jsp ....... 
i want to ask that how could i be able to access my webapp only through  mygodaddydomainname.com instead of mygodaddydomainname.com/webappname/pagename.jsp ... 
by default mygodaddydomainname.com is equivalent to localhost which opens homepage of apache tomcat server.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the root directory for your web server. For Apache Tomcat, it should be `CATALINA_BASE` if I'm not mistaken. Follow [clmarquart's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077070/3209381) to configure that.

More info: [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html)